# How to let the screen go to standby when scheme is running in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appdelegate, lldb

[image]

When the scheme is running, the iPhone screen stays on. The bug that I'm trying to reproduce only occurs when the screen goes to standby **by itself**. When stopping the running scheme, I don't have breakpoints anymore.. So I'm looking for a way for the screen to go to standby by itself, but it has to stay connected to the debugger. When using the physical button, the bug does not occur.

Many thanks guys!!!

Comment: Can anyone help out? I really need to finish this job in about a few days :S Many thanks guys!

Comment: Usually in both cases the same methods are called. Like applicationdidEnterBackground: in your app delegate.

Comment: @Thomas the problem is that applicationdidEnterBackground does not get called... And I cannot NSLog / Debug because the screen does not go to standby when connected to Debugger.

Comment: Does applicationWillResignActive: get called?

Comment: @Thomas When stopping the running scheme, I do not have breakpoints or NSLog, so there is no way for me to verify. What I can say, is that when I use the physical button, the applicationWillResignActive does gets called and app behaves normal. So I could conclude that it does not get called.

Comment: You could store a timestamp along with an ID in NSUserDefaults to check if any of these methods get called when you are not debugging and the screen turns off. As I am interested in this, I'll try it out for myself, too.

Comment: I made a simple test application to check if any of these methods get called, and they do (as supposed to).